# How to execute a AS400 command through Mule AS400 connector ? And how to check the response?

Tags: mule, ibm-midrange

According to the example in below link 
https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/call-ibmi-command-example?searchTerm=AS400&sortBy=name

I have try to use the Mule AS400 connector to execute a CRTPF command, but after the connector is processed in Mule flow, the file cannot be created successfully, and I do not know what happened, hence no log and no exception can be catch. Can anyone have similar experience ?

Comment: While you are running your connector are you able to be logged into your AS/400 running the WRKACTJOB command to look out for the job log there?

Comment: As it is development machine that shared by many user, so I cannot locate my job easily. Do you have idea which subsystem the job will be in ? And I have try to user WRKUSRJOB to find the job under my profile, but nothing can be found.

Comment: I don't think it will be easy to find, and I'm not sure how your system is configured so don't know which subsystem, if I had to guess, I would try looking at joblogs for QZDASOINIT.

Comment: Thank you, Mike, let me try this.

Comment: I know the team that made the as400 mule connector I'll ping them to look at your question.

Comment: We need to see some code

Comment: You can locate your jobs in green-screen by using command WRKOBJLCK OBJ( yourUserID ) OBJTYPE(*USRPRF). When multiple jobs of yours are listed, some practice and experience will help you zero in on ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

The connector executes remote commands in QZRCSRVS jobs. You can list all remote command jobs using `wrkactjob job(QZRCSRVS)`.

If the command fails, the connector pulls all messages from the job log and throws the exception that can be trapped in Exception Strategy. The exception cause should have all messages coming from the back end (both message text and additional details).

Comment: You can get to the exception details via exception.cause, something like: 

`<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy"> 
            <logger message="#[&quot;Error adding member &quot; + exception.cause]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
        </catch-exception-strategy>`